# How can I get a Binary Operator from a Class?

Tags: java, sum, binary-operators

Is there a way to get the Binary Operator related to a class?
I have this method that has two parameters:

```
    public <T extends Number> T[] sumArray(T[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<T> add){
        T[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] = add.apply(arrayToReturn[i], arrayToAdd[j]);
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
```

However, I'd like to do something like this:

```
    public <T extends Number> T[] sumArray(T[] arrayToAdd){
        BinaryOperator add = arrayToAdd.getClass().getBinaryOperator(sum);
        T[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] = add.apply(arrayToReturn[i], arrayToAdd[j]);
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
```

- Important: The method  `.getBinaryOperator(sum)` doesn't exists.

PD: I'm also having problems with the first method when calling it from another class:
`api.sumArray(intArray, Integer::sum);`
The error says: 'Object is not convertible to int'

------------------edit------------------

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
public class guide6Main<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Number> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiArray api = new ApiArray();
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        api.exercise6(intArray, Integer::sum);
     }
}
```

```
public class ApiArray<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Number> {
    public  <N extends Number> N[] exercise6(N[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<N> add){
        N[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] =add.apply(arrayToReturn[i],arrayToAdd[j] );
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
D:\Documentos\Austral\Álgerba III\src\Guia6\Team2Solution\guide6Main.java:11:49
java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int
```

P.D.2: Also, `arrayToAdd` cannot contain a mixture of types, I mean, it could, but not in this case
(Is the  minimal reproducible example okay? I've never done something like that)

Comment: "`intArray`" is that an `int[]` or an `Integer[]`?

Comment: "I'd like to do something like this" Sorry, you just can't, at least not in a fully generic way. After all, `arrayToAdd` could contain a mixture of types (e.g. some `Double`, some `Integer`, some `BigInteger`).

Comment: @AndyTurner `Integer[]`.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] which reproduces the "Object is not convertible to int" error.

Comment: The nature of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) makes it hard to do it the way presented in the question. It should, however, be possible to pass a `Class<T>` instance along and get a method called `sum` that takes two `T`s as parameters via reflection. I am, however, unsure if I would recommend this approach over the current implementation since the current implementation looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've edited the post, should I change something else?

Comment: @AndyTurner `could contain a mixture of types (e.g. some Double, some Integer, some BigInteger).` Sure it can but that is not a problem as the array *produces* values (getting values out of that array). So they just have to be numbers because the method says: _Whatever you provide, it at least has to be a number!_ The return type is also bound to N which is at least a Number which is also totally fine.

Comment: @DanielWosch it's a problem insofar as OP is trying to derive a binary operator from a type. You can't derive it from the element type of the array (`Number`, which has no binary operators); you'll struggle to derive it from the types of the elements of the array, if they're different.

Comment: @PedroElizaldeAcevedo "incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int" derives from the fact that `ApiArray` is a generic class, but `ApiArray api` is a raw-typed variable. Raw types erase all generics, even those unrelated to the omitted type parameters. Declare it as `ApiArray<?, ?> api` (or remove the type parameters).

Comment: But declaring the array N as Integer Array will lead to an type inference(?) for the BinaryOperator to be a BinaryOperator<Integer>. If I change the type of the array the type of the BinaryOperator will automatically be infered (damn I hope I have the term correctly in my brain..)

Comment: OP is asking to do it *without* the explicit BinaryOperator. Of course you can do it with the explicit BinaryOperator, and the compiler will stop you passing an incompatible type.

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought about providing a Function returning a BinaryOperator based on the class provided to that function. The BinaryOperator should then be obtained from a Map<? ex Number, BinaryOperator<? ex Number>>... but that does also not work due to the fact that the returning BinaryOperator is always BinaryOperator<Number> thanks to the type system. Okay tbh. there seems no way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering purely about the error "`incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int`":

```
public class guide6Main<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Number> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiArray api = new ApiArray();
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        api.exercise6(intArray, Integer::sum);
     }
}

public class ApiArray<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Number> {
    public  <N extends Number> N[] exercise6(N[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<N> add){
        // ...
    }
}
```

`ApiArray` is a generic type, but `ApiArray api` is a raw-typed variable (it has no type parameters).

Raw types erase all generics, even those unrelated to the omitted type parameters.

Either declare `api` using wildcard types:

```
    ApiArray<?, ?> api = new ApiArray<>();
```

(Or, obviously, put in non-wildcard types there, if there are types you can usefully add).

If they're not necessary, remove the type parameters from the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your class design is not optimal at this point.
Your method hides the class parameter of `N`.

So when you do

```
ApiArray api = new ApiArray();
Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
api.exercise6(intArray, Integer::sum);
```

You are using a raw type (*see ApiArray api without providing a type*)  which will lead to `N` being just `object` as `N` is not bound to any type at this point. This will lead to `N` being erased to `Object` because `Object` is the least most super type.

Therefore you need to provide the generic types for `T` and `N` when instantiating your `ApiArray` class - for example:

```
 ApiArray<Integer, Integer> api = new ApiArray();
 Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
 api.exercise6(intArray, Integer::sum );
```

---

Another way to achieve your result is to remove the generic type bounds of your class:

```
class ApiArray {
    public  <N extends Number> N[] exercise6(N[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<N> add){
        N[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                arrayToReturn[i] =add.apply(arrayToReturn[i],arrayToAdd[j] );
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn;
    }
}
```

Here the generic types / bounds are provided by the method signature.

---

Another approach would be to remove the generic type parameters from your method and use the generic type parameter bounds from the class itself:

```
class ApiArray<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Number> {
public N[] exercise6(N[] arrayToAdd, BinaryOperator<N> add){
    N[] arrayToReturn =  arrayToAdd.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToAdd.length; i++) {
        arrayToReturn[i] = arrayToAdd[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            arrayToReturn[i] =add.apply(arrayToReturn[i],arrayToAdd[j] );
        }
    }
    return arrayToReturn;
}
}


  ApiArray<Integer, Integer> api = new ApiArray();
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        api.exercise6(intArray, Integer::sum );
```